# PHP Not Recognizing Array in HTML Form "name" Attribute

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, post

I have a list of  and  fields where users enter the name of an item and the quantity. The PHP function

```
 generateMaterialsTable();
```

is responsible for generating one text field and one number field if there are no existing records in the database. If there are multiples, the function shows all items and their corresponding quantities. Here is the PHP code:

```
 function generateMaterialsTable($month_id, $table, $item, $addOrEdit){
     global $mysqli;

     $item_singular = substr($item, 0, strlen($item)-1);
     $item_singular_title = $item_singular.'_title';

     if($addOrEdit == 'Edit'){
        $materials_query = "SELECT * FROM archivestats.".$table."_".$item." WHERE month_id = '$month_id'";
        $materials_result = $mysqli->query($materials_query);
        if($materials_result->num_rows > 0){
            $counter = 1;
            while($materials_match = $materials_result->fetch_assoc()){
                $output .= '
                    <div class="form-group '.$item_singular.'-row row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" name="'.$item_singular.'[]" class="form-control item-field" value="'.htmlentities($materials_match[$item_singular_title]).'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="number" name="'.$item_singular.'qty[]" class="form-control align-right '.$item_singular.'qty" value="'.$materials_match['quantity'].'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  ';
            $counter++;
        }
     } else {
        $output .= '
            <div class="form-group '.$item_singular.'-row row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="'.$item_singular.'[]" class="form-control item-field" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="number" name="'.$item_singular.'qty[]" class="form-control align-right '.$item_singular.'qty" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
  }
    return $output;
  }
```

The user also has the option to add a new text and quantity field. This is done via the following JQuery:

```
 //WHEN USER CLICKS '+Add Another Field'
 $('.new-field').click(function(){  
    var newFieldId = $(this).attr('id'); //find id of the '+Add Another Field' paragraph

    var newField = newFieldId.substr(0, newFieldId.lastIndexOf('-')); //find the name of the field before the last - (eg. 'book' from 'book-new')
    var fields = $(this).parents().siblings().closest('.'+newField+'-row').find('input[type="text"]');

    var count = 0; 
    $(fields).each(function(){
        //we only need to get information for the last text box in the bunch
        if(count == fields.length-1){
            var last_field = $(this).attr('name'); //the name attribute of the last text box
            var field_name = last_field.substr(0, last_field.indexOf('[')); //find the name of the field before a _ (eg. 'book' from 'book_1')
            var regEx = /\d+/; //find the number of the field contained in the name (eg. '1' from 'book_1')
            var field_number = parseInt(last_field.match(regEx));

            $(this).parent().parent().after('<div class="form-group '+ field_name +'-row row">    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="'+ field_name +'[]" class="form-control item-field"></div><div class="col-sm-4 add-field"><input type="number" name="'+ field_name +'qty[]" class="form-control align-right ' + field_name + 'qty"></div></div>');
    }
        count++; //iterate our counter      
    });
 }); //end .new-feild.click()
```

For whatever reason, when I go to submit the form, the array as defined in

```
 name="'.$item_singular.'[]"
```

only works properly with one group of text fields - that is, it properly records all array items. For example, let's say I have the following:

```
 <div class="form-group book-row row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="book[]" class="form-control item-field">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" name="bookqty[]" class="form-control align-right bookqty">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group book-row row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="book[]" class="form-control item-field">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" name="bookqty[]" class="form-control align-right bookqty">
    </div>
 </div>
```

For this, I will input values of EXAMPLE 1 / 4 and EXAMPLE 2 / 15. When I submit and do:

```
print_r($_POST['book'])
```

I get the proper value of

```
Array([0] => "Example 1", [1] => "Example 2")
```

But then in another section of that EXACT SAME FORM I do this:

```
 <div class="form-group book-row row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" name="digbook[]" class="form-control item-field">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="digbookqty[]" class="form-control align-right digbookqty">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group book-row row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="digbook[]" class="form-control item-field">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" name="digbookqty[]" class="form-control align-right digbookqty">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this, I will input values of EXAMPLE 3 / 1 and EXAMPLE 4 / 20. Now I'll **get ONLY the first item in the array**:

```
Array([0] => "Example 3")
```

This makes absolutely no sense and it is driving me crazy. It is the exact same function spitting out the exact same code with two completely different results. Unreal...

Comment: you should use name="digbookqty[2]" as name="digbookqty[]". Remove 1, 2 inside name array and then try

Comment: Your html does not match the posted php. There should be `value` attributes in all cases.

Comment: Thinking Web: still doesn't work. Still only getting result of first item.

Comment: Why explicitly specify the array index numbers?

Comment: I guess I don't really need to for this example. In other areas of my system I needed the specific index numbers to store records in the database in order of priority.

Comment: It is not necessary to use concatenation in your markup, php has string interpolation and automatically recognizes multi-line string literals.